# Is there any pandas or numpy alternative to nested for loops?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I've written the following simple function, but it's running rather slow.
For df1 I'm using a dataframe without any column (only index) and for df2 I'm using a dataframe with 10 columns and trying to add one df2's columns along with it's value to df1 if the indices match.

```
def add_labels_column(df1, df2):
    for idx1 in df1.index:
        for idx2 in df2.index:
            if idx1 == idx2:
                df1['Finding Labels'] = df2['Finding Labels']
    return df1
```

I'm looking for a faster solution, perhaps using pandas and/or numpy. I'm a new to Python, pandas or numpy.

Comment: Use [Minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to post your code so that others can reproduce your problem and help solving.

Comment: There are several options, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65167356/11380795) thread.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen Thank you!, the merge function was exactly what I needed!, now I feel silly for not being able to figure out something like this..

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer your question without sample data, but one possible option is:

```
df1['Finding Labels'] = df1['Finding Labels'].update(df2['Finding Labels'])
```